# Facebook like button is not working on my Page

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

This is the lik: http://portali.com.mk/lajmi/2778, try to click the like button end you will see.

this is the code inside html tag :

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

This is the XFBML Code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=212833985438245";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and this is my like butoon:

```
   <fb:like href="<?php echo CurrentPageURL() ?>" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

What I am doing wrong, this problem is killing me for 1 week ?

Answer (score 0):

Response from facebook on click on Like :

> There was an error liking the page. If you are the page owner, please try running your page through the linter on the Facebook devsite (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) and fixing any errors

[Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fportali.com.mk%2Flajmi%2F) shows that page dosent have any meta tags.
You must generate this tags for each page that can be liked. Use [generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#oggenerator) for meta tags. Put generated tags in HEAD section of page and check page with [Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fportali.com.mk%2Flajmi%2F). If debugger dosent show any errors than Like button must work.

Comment: All Meta tags are there, i have created them. Bu the way the link is  http://portali.com.mk/lajmi/2789, not  http://portali.com.mk/lajm/

Comment: Ok. Meta tags looks good but you make mistake in "og:image". You are using image with URL: http://www.poortali.com/userfiles/image/13_08_2012/ksander1.gif that dosn't exist. Fix it.

Comment: Put correct url. For example : http://portali.com.mk/userfiles/image/13_08_2012/ksander.gif